# Does the number of corpses affect research?

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

If I'm low on space and have some 11 corpses of each alien but haven't researched any, should I keep the pile of bodies around to improve research or can I sell all but one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In UFO Defence - unlike in EU2012 - corpses are never needed for secondary R&D once they've been autopsied. You can freely sell all but one corpse (or, if you've already autopsied one, all of them). Indeed, this is a major source of income earlier on, although selling unwanted UFO components and weapons generally outstrips it by the end of the first year.

Live aliens are a different story, since you can only interrogate each one once, but interrogating multiple live aliens of the same species and rank can give you new research each time - for example, interrogating a Medic will get you information about other alien species, and an Engineer will get you UFO data.

Answer (score 4):

You only need one corpse of each species.

Live prisoners, now...

Comment: ...are still required only one of each. Which can still be difficult.

Comment: i can't see live prisoners anywhere. got 4 reapers, did the research... what happens? do they that from the 10 spaces forever? or are they gone already?

Comment: @Humungus Yes, but they don't take up storage space as long as you have an alien containment facility to put them in.

Comment: Also, one of each type *and* one of each profession. He's asking about the original game, not the remake.

Comment: Didn't the alien containment use to have a capacity? But yes, you are right. Each profession does something else. Interrogating a common grunt for super secret base coordinates would be useless.

Comment: i think my version is bogus. I got 3 reaper. and i keep seeing them as available research. i already have his file. i tried researching a second time. it shows the research complete and when you click the results, it is a blank screen. and i still have it available to research again (probably because i had 3)

Comment: It has been my experience that, in order to do research on a corpse, I merely needed one to exist in my base's inventory. The research became instantly available at that base and I could immediately sell the related corpse(s), and that a corpse wasn't necessary to complete research on it. Is this right?